# Creating nested form in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-forms

I am trying to render a partial which I have set up as the following. I have am also trying to create a nested form whereby I have included `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user` in my hospital_bookings model. I seem to be getting the following error:

> NameError in Rota_days#index
>
> Showing
>   C:/Users/home/Desktop/Portal/app/views/rota_days/index.html.erb
>   where line #31 raised:
>
> undefined local variable or method `hospital_booking' for

which is pointing to the following line `<%=  render :partial => "booking_dialog", :locals => { :booking => hospital_booking.new } %>` of my index.html.erb as shown below. I thought it was something to do with my pluralization. By changing `hospital_bookings.new` to `hospital_booking.new` but this did not work

**_booking_dialog.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for booking do |f| %> 
     <%= f.fields_for :user do |f| %>
        <br/>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <br/>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :hospital_id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :id unless booking.new_record? %>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hospital_booking.new` is nonsensical: you have no local variable named `hospital_booking`. If you want a new instance of the `HospitalBooking` model, then you want `HospitalBooking.new`.

So:

```
<%=  render :partial => "booking_dialog", :locals => { :booking => HospitalBooking.new } %>
```

**Update** (from the comments)

In the `booking_dialog` form partial, you need to put the `name` attribute on the associated `user` record inside a [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) block, to distinguish it from the fields for the parent (booking):

```
<%= form_for booking do |f| %>
  <%= fields_for :user do |user_fields| %>
    <%= user_fields.label :name %>
    <%= user_fields.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :hospital_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id unless booking.new_record? %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

p.s. it seems very strange that you have a hidden field for the `:id` in here. You shouldn't need that.

Comment: I followed this, and then was given the following error `undefined method `name' for #<HospitalBooking:0x45275d0>` although I have specified in my hospital_booking.rb `accept_nested_attributes_for :user`

Comment: Yes but you can't simply use a nested attribute as if it was an attribute of the parent model, you have to use a `fields_for :user` block. See the documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for .

Comment: Ahh right I noticed on the following that I needed to do something like `<%= f.fields_for :user do |f| %>` if I am correct.

Comment: Yes that is correct, then put the text field inside that block.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You went overboard with `fields_for`: you don't need to replace the whole form, just wrap the fields for the associated record (user) in a `fields_for` block. (I've never actually used this method before, I'm just working from the docs.)

Comment: p.s. this goes beyond the question you originally asked, which I think I've answered with my original answer.

Comment: p.p.s. I don't think you need the hidden `id` field in there, that should be implied by the URL you post the form to.